# How add show/hide eye icon inside textbox?

Tags: html, css

Hello I was developing UI for Login page and I need to use my own css for that purpose, I tried lot of solutions and code in lot of ways but I did not get success. Every time if icon appears then it comes outside of textbox and still non clickable. So let me know what I am doing wrong here?

**login page**

```css
.password-field-cls {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(145, 158, 171, 0.32);
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="password" class="password-field-cls" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" aria-describedby="input-password" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off">
<span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
<span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
```

Also suggest me CDN link for icons

Comment: This question is about HTML and CSS; the use of ASP.NET is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: you can position absolute the icon and make parent position relative to achieve the solution or make the icon relative and adjust with Float. Here is a similar guide:
https://codepen.io/Sohail05/pen/yOpeBm